# Pass variables to view within Devise

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise 3.2.4. I'm overwriting the SessionsController with this:

```
  def create
    super do |resource|
      @just_signed_in = true
    end
  end
```

The goal is to be able to use the variable `@just_signed_in` in the view in order to trigger front-end JavaScript that should only be called upon log in. Here's how my `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` is defined:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    return root_path
  end
```

Given the `return root_path`, I don't think that allows `@just_signed_in` to be passed to the view. How can I trigger JavaScript after user signs in? Am I missing something?

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason that your variable is not available to the view is because of the `respond_with` which is performed by devise's `create` after yielding to your block which sets @just_signed_in.  If everything has been successful, then this `respond_with` will perform a `redirect_to`, so your @just_signed_in variable will not survive to be available to the controller which handles your `root_path` (see `navigation_behaviour()` in ActionController module in rails' actionpack in `actionpack/lib/controller/metal` which shows the redirect_to for success or render for failure).

One way around this is to add an attribute to your `resource` as Rich suggested and then you can get hold of it using `current_user` in your view and check/reset it (ideally with logic in the model rather than the view).  If you don't want to add an attribute to your resource/model, another approach is to put your "just signed in" flag in the session instead, and just access/remove it in the view.  i.e. instead of:

```
@just_signed_in = true
```

have:

```
session[:just_signed_in] = true
```

and then in your view, do something like:

```
if session.delete(:just_signed_in)
  …whatever…
end
```

You might like to hide this in a view helper, especially if you need it in more than one place.

Comment: One note, the syntax you posted didn't work. I need to do: `session.delete(:just_signed_in)` with parenthesis instead of brackets.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/sessions_controller.rb#L15) is the source for `Devise` `sessions#create`:

```
def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_flashing_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
end
```

--

**Problem**

I think your problem will be you're calling `super` before you set the `@just_signed_in` variable. To the best of my knowledge, calling `super` in this way will call the entire method you're trying to append [need to research how to use `super do |var|`]...

If my theory is correct, it means your `@just_signed_in` variable is not being set, consequently preventing it from being available. I originally presumed the `after_sign_in_path_for` would be a `redirect`, but as it just sets the location, it *should* have the variable set *if* it's done correctly

**Update**

I have since found the [reference you used](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers):

```
class Admins::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  def create
    super do |resource|
      BackgroundWorker.trigger(resource)
    end
  end
end
```

---

**Fix**

There are several things you need to do:

**Make sure your `sessions_controller` override is working**

You have not posted your class declaration for your `sessions_controller`. It might seem simplistic, but the simplest things often cause the biggest errors!

You need to have this:

```
#config/routes.rb
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "your/sessions" }

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
Class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
   ... 
end
```

-

**Make sure your `@just_signed_in` variable is set**

Your variable may not be available in the view for a number of reasons (redirects etc). I would highly recommend setting up some `logs` to track if you've set the `@just_signed_in` variable:

```
#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def create
   super do |resource|
       @just_signed_in = true
       Rails.logger.info(@just_signed_in.inspect)
   end
end
```

This will at least confirm if the variable has been set (and therefore there will be something else at fault)

-

**See where `@just_signed_in` is available to**

Further to the second step, I would then try to see where `@just_signed_in` is available to. I would do this by appending the value to your `resource`, and then using a `logger` in your `after_sign_in_path_for(resource)` method:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessor :just_signed_in
end

#app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb
def create
    super do |resource|
        resource.just_signed_in = true
    end 
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    Rails.logger.info(resource.just_signed_in.inspect)
end
```

---

I hope this helps - I don't know if any of this will work, but it will certainly create a better environment to discover the answer!